# Typescript utility function to make Axios requests

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I'm trying to make a utility function for Axios requests.

I started by making an alias of `AxiosConfig` at `global.d.ts`:

```
import { Method } from 'axios';
export {};

declare global { 
    type AxiosConfig = {url: string, method: Method, data: object};
}
```

Then, at my `utils.ts` I created the following function:

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import * as https from 'https';

export async function axiosReq(options: AxiosConfig): Promise<AxiosResponse<unknown, any>> {
  try {
    const data = await axios({
        url: options.url,
        method: options.method,
        data: options.data,
        httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
          rejectUnauthorized: false
        })
    });
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch videos...')
  }
}
```

Finally, using the function:

```
import { axiosReq } from "../utils";

const AxiosConfig = { 
    url: 'https://172.24.14.12/api/baseline', 
    method: 'POST',
    data: {}
    };
const res = await axiosReq(AxiosConfig);
```

The node crashes at the start (even before using `axiosReq`).
Only when I comment out `const res = await axiosReq(AxiosConfig)` node starts without crashing.
I don't receive any informative errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get errors in `utils.ts`. 1) `Cannot find name 'AxiosConfig'` and 2) `Generic type 'AxiosResponse<T>' requires between 0 and 1 type arguments.ts(2707)`

Answer (score 0):

You're treating AxiosConfig as a value or variable when it's really just a type.  Try

```
const postBaseline: AxiosConfig = {...
```

then replace AxiosConfig in the res call with postBaseline

Comment: Still crashes on start, even without calling the function yet.